MFC SDI Application ->Print -> Print Dialog -> Help button click not working in x64 configuration after adding OnHelp Handler
I have created a sample MFC SDI application using MFC Standard style. I added the following handler in MainFrm.cpp:
ON_COMMAND(ID_HELP,&CMainFrame::OnHelp)
I ran the application, select Print, in the print dialog, click "Help" it works in x86 configuration, but it is not working x64. Control is not coming to OnHelp in x64.
How can I debug this?
